# API gateway for rest API?

Tags: node.js, security, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a rest API which developed with loopback framework. And my datastore is mssql. What are my options for API gateway which is easy to integrate?

Kindly suggest

Comment: You need to provide more information before anyone can give a useful answer. What is it that you need exactly, and what requirements do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was referring to any api gateway such as amazon api gateway.
I have started implementing the same